# Can't set custom taxonomy terms via custom form

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

### Question

I am creating my first plugin and in it users will be able (among other things) to create new post via custom form from wordpress backend. This post uses custom post type and custom taxonomy. Form creates new post but it fails to set custom taxomony.

Creating post regularly (not via my custom form) works fine ie. allows me to add custom taxomony to it.

Custom post type and custom taxonomies are registered by the book, terms are already inserted in db.

**taxonomy is not a variable for debugging purposes*

```
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'newpost');

    function newpost() {
        if (isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') {
            $post_title = $_POST['posttitle'];
            $post_content = $_POST['postcontent'];
            $new_post = array(
                'ID' => '',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'cars',
                'post_content' => $post_content,
                'post_title' => $post_title,
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tax_input' => array('cars' => array('bmw', 'audi'))
            );

            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        }
    }
```

I've even tried to remove **'tax_input'** and use **wp_set_post_terms** and **wp_set_object_terms** but results were same. Two days I'm stuck on this, so any help would be greatly appreciated...

### Solution

The solution was to change **plugins_loaded** to **init** with low priority.

```
   add_action( 'init', 'newpost', 200 );
```

So the issue was that user privileges have not yet been set, upon firing the plugin.

Comment: well I can at least tell you with certainty that the method you've shown in your code (via `wp_insert_post`) will definitely not work if the person submitting the form is not a logged in user with the capability to assign post terms. I use `wp_set_object_terms` for front-end forms. are both your taxonomy and post type named `cars`?

Comment: User has all capabilities needed, as plugin is intended to be used only from backend. Btw. I'm testing as Super Admin. Actually those are not named `cars`, but still they dont share the same name. I'm going to test plugin on the other server as it is last option I can think of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `wp_set_object_terms?` ...which needs to be placed after your call to `wp_insert_post` as it requires the post ID in order to attach the correct terms, to the right taxonomy with the right post.

```
//add_action('plugins_loaded', 'newpost'); # will not work, user not authenticated

add_action('init', 'newpost'); // will work, user authenticated
function newpost() {
    if (isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') {
        $post_title = $_POST['posttitle'];
        $post_content = $_POST['postcontent'];
        $taxonomy = 'cars'; //change accordingly...
        $terms = $_POST['tax_terms']; //change accordingly... 
        $new_post = array(
            'ID' => '',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'cars',
            'post_content' => $post_content,
            'post_title' => $post_title,
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        //$terms can be an array of term IDs/slugs
        //$taxonomy is your taxonomy name, e.g. cars
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy );
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try `wp_set_object_terms` and `wp_set_post_terms` also. Tried it on other server and still not working. Fresh WP install, with no plugins. Will look back into this in a few days with clear mind...

Comment: After further inspection `plugins_loaded` hook will not work for this purpose. Switch to `init`, or `wp`. Reason it won't work is because the user is not authenticated in the system at `plugins_loaded` which is what `wp_insert_post` needs, so any hook below `after_setup_theme` including it, works.

Comment: You got me on right track, changing it just to `init` didn't help, but making it low priority did. Check updated question for solution. Tnx :)

Comment: Glad you have it working. The correct solution for this question is to not use `plugins_loaded` hook for this purpose as `wp_insert_post` does not have require permissions at this point. The priority of the `init` hook is subjective to your setup, for me it works at the default priority, for you, there might be some other processes hooked onto `init` at higher priorities getting in your way. Now that this question is solved please don't forget to mark the answer and close out the question. All the best.